# can we show checkbox for selection in RDLC?

Tags: report, rdlc, viewer

Here my requirement is 
I want to show one checkbox in RDLC report that has to be selective in the runtime.
if that checkbox is checked, one set of rows has to be bind to table. for example 4 rows has to be display in Report
if i uncheck the checkbox, then another set of rows has to bind to table. for example 10 rows has to be dispaly in rdlc report.

FYI we are showing rdlc report using microsoft report viewer and using C# code for windows application.

Answer (score 0):

There is no checkbox in rdlc AFAIK